# how to change port of wamp server and how to create first application

Tags: php, port, wamp

i have just instsalled wamp server but when i'm trying to access localhost it is not accessible I think it is problem with the port because wamp uses port 80 by default.
and after that i want to create a dynamic website i've never used php in past so i want to know how to get satarted ...
thanks

I have tried in another system . I installed wamp and saw that localhost is accesible there but when i connected to the internet by modem wamp server stop working . I am totally confused about this port setting . I have unplugged lan cable from my laptop and restated the system then tried even it is not working .. i have changed httpd.conf file but it doesn't helps me

Comment: if skype is your problem with port 80 you should disable that and let wamp take over 80. in skype: tools->options->advanced->connection uncheck the use port 80 thing. This is a very typical conflict, so forgive me if I am making useless assumptions.

Comment: @KaiQing I have found that if I log into the WAMP server first, and then follow up by logging into Skype, they both work on port 80.

Comment: if skype is on , close it & try! ,so at least you will get to what is the problem(port no or something else)!

Comment: but i don't think this is due to skype because i'm not logged in

Comment: @abhisheksingh Port no is all about an application(e.g. SKYPE) and not about the state of the running application. so the port no only deals with SKYPE and not with ur status in SKYPE i.e. either logged in or not doesn't matter with the port no used by skype i.e here 80.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all change `Listen 80` to `Listen PORT YOU WANT` in Apache httpd.conf file.

Now in the same file search for the word vhost you will find it three time just uncomment it by removing # from beginning of statement (you will find it two time in one statement) .

Now open http-vhosts.conf file which is inside `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\extra\` and paste below code with port modification and you are done.

Using this you can set more than one port to different directory.

```
<VirtualHost *:5>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
           <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
                       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                       AllowOverride all
                       Order allow,deny
                       Allow from all
           </Directory>
   #ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
   #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error_log"
   #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access_log common"

</VirtualHost>
```

just change `<VirtualHost *:5>` this to whatever port you need and restart Apache and all other service.

Now Cheers.
Enjoy

Answer (score 5):

For change wamp server port number :

```
1. Go to \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\conf
2. Open  “httpd.conf” in notepad
3. Find “Listen 80” and Change it to your desired port
   (for example : Listen 8081)
4. Save it and close it .
```

Restart wamp server and check.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started on your

`C:/wamp/www` directory there you would put all your files its up to you how you structure you files.

AND if you are using skype, try running wampserver before opening skype, skype uses port 80 as with the default wampserver port. OPEN wampserver before using skype. No Problem and No Need To change PORT. also not only skype but other programs to uses PORT 80, before doing anything OPEN wamp first before other programs.

Answer (score 0):

After using google, I found the answer for you.

Open httpd.conf and find the line with: Listen 80

80 is the port number, so change it to any number you want.

[more links to help you out](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+default+port+of+wamp&aq=f&oq=change+default+port+of+wamp&aqs=chrome.0.57j0.5978&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=change+default+port+of+wamp+server&oq=change+default+port+of+wamp+server&gs_l=serp.3..33i29.4428.5590.0.5730.7.7.0.0.0.0.109.714.3j4.7.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.Xr0fTaWIuEY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41524429,d.aWc&fp=99bbb1d5e9938d35&biw=1006&bih=647)

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work for me ...

Comment: Did you restart the service?